# Getting redirected url from instagram server

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I am grabbing images from instagram and am receiving urls like "http://instagram.com/p/1JiWygQUSu/media/?size=l" the issue is this url directs to "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/e15/1527608_451589571655110_1239072675_n.jpg" I need the file extension to properly cache the image on a user device.

The first url is redirecting to the second. I need a way to retrieve the second url from the first.

Tried using this code but it just returns the original url:

```
let urlString = "http://instagram.com/p/1JiWygQUSu/media/?size=l"
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:urlString)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
    (response, data, error) in
    print("instaResponse \(response?.URL)")
})
```

Comment: Just extract lastPathComponent from the redirected url

Comment: How are you grabbing these images? Are you using a library like AFNetworking? Are you using NSURLSession?

Comment: I'm using nsurlsession

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` method 
`- URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:` [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:).

You should be able to handle the redirect there and cache the image. Alternatively, you can try using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which have image caching built in, and probably handle the redirect case already.